# Why do all the Recompose recipes start with "const { Component } = React;"

Tags: reactjs, recompose

Why do all the Recompose recipes start with `const { Component } = React;` when they don't use `Component`, or do they?

What's the significance of starting the recipe like that?

https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/wiki/Recipes

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the use of JSX in the code. JSX is transpiled to React.createElement, which obviously uses React.